# Service locator - why not use DNS?

Tags: dns, soa, microservices

There are a lot of applications that can take role of Service Locator in distributed environment AKA SOA. For example, Zookeeper and Consul. Why not use DNS instead?

- Standard, well-known, stable
- Distributed, fault-tolerant
- Can assign multiple IPs to the same name for load balancing in homogeneous clusters
- Can serve additional metadata

So... why not?

Comment: I've used it very effectively as a "service catalog". One of the developers and I tied the bare metal build scripts to a non-privileged user account on my hidden master server where I could INCLUDE his automatically built files into the main DNS infrastructure. Worked very well. To address availability, you're better off to have something like an actual load-balancer in front of the services with active probing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @igorbel for interesting article leading to more interesting articles on topic.

As for answer, DNS can't be good solution because of:

- Complex centralized configuration. That really complicates adding new hosts.
- Large and unpredictable propagation time. Removing failed node can take some time due to layered DNS caching which leads to longer periods of system instability.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can use DNS. Many times you should. But, if your needs are greater than what DNS offers and you need to build something custom on top of it, you can check already existing tools like ZooKeeper, Consul, etcd, Eureka and others.

You might decide to use them if you have a problem they can solve.

For example, you might want to detect when your service goes down or loses connectivity - and remove the affected endpoints from the list of your services. All of the mentioned tools offer this out of the box.

There is a nice writeup by Spotify relevant to this topic:
https://labs.spotify.com/2013/02/25/in-praise-of-boring-technology

Answer (score 0):

The DNS protocol for discovery is a good option - this is why tools like [SkyDNS] (for etcd) [1](https://github.com/skynetservices/skydns) and [Consol](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html) support it for exactly this purpose.

It is better to use these tools that just DNS since they provide additional capabilities like leader election, healthcheck etc.